# javascript for changing outputlabel whenever input value is changed

Tags: javascript

I have a input field with date

```
 date = 1/16/2013 (in the form of inputtext)
```

whenever I change this input text their is an another output text where this value should reflect

```
date1 = 1/16/2013 (in the form of outputtext)
```

so whenever date is changed date1 should be rendered accordingly.

how can I get it with javascript.

```
<script>
 function invoicedate(){
     var transaction = jQuery.trim(jQuery(".transaction").val());
    // alert(transaction);
 }
</script>
<apex:page>
 <apex:pageblocksection>
    date
      <apex:inputText value="{!ChargeDate}" styleclass="transaction" onblur="invoicedate"/>
    date1
      <apex:outputlabel value="{!chargedate}" styleclass="transaction" />
  </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: included the code.

Comment: If you use unique id's instead of classes you should get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give both of the elements a unique id instead of a class. Then use the ids to get the value from one field and put it in the other:

```
<script>
 function invoicedate(){
     //note the special jQuery identifier to get the visualforce-generated id
     var transaction = jQuery.trim(jQuery("[id$=transaction_input]").val());
     jQuery("[id$=transaction_output]").val(transaction);
    // alert(transaction);
 }
</script>
<apex:page>
 <apex:pageblocksection>
    date
      <apex:inputText value="{!ChargeDate}" id="transaction_input" onblur="invoicedate"/>
    date1
      <apex:outputlabel value="{!chargedate}" id="transaction_output" />
  </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: no change Lex. only the first value is displayed after that it is not changing

Comment: And if you alert the value of `transaction`?

Comment: Try using `jQuery("[id$=transaction_output]").html(transaction);` instead of `jQuery("[id$=transaction_output]").val(transaction);`

Comment: instead of displaying date1 as outputlabel I need to display it in inputtext. then how should I declare in js?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly; for inputTexts you use `.val()` and for outputLabel you use `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!account.site}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="text1"  onchange="writehello();" value="{!account.SLAExpirationDate__c}" />
            <apex:outputText label="Form" id="hello2"/>
            <script>
            function writehello() {
             // alert('Component id = "{!$Component.text1}"');
              var a= document.getElementById("{!$Component.text1}").value;
              //alert('Value'+a);
              document.getElementById("{!$Component.hello2}").innerHTML = a;    
            }
           </script>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

just tried and the above code works fine for me .I created a date field and my simple hello script works perfectly